# Spring Data JPA FindAll returns incorrect values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql, informix

I have written code to connect Informix DB and fetch values. I am able to connect the DB and fetch a specific table value. But If I go and insert some values manually in DB and try to fetch the values from code, I am not getting the correct values in `findAll()` response.

```
Ex: 
Table Name: XXX_XXX
ser dt           crnt_ts    ser_status
1   2017-11-07  18:15:29    UP
2   2017-11-07  18:15:29    UP
3   2017-11-07  18:15:29    UP
4   2017-11-07  18:15:29    UP
5   2017-11-07  18:15:29    DOWN
```

Now I am getting a proper response from `findALL()` method.
Inserted server 6 with UP status and different time stamp.

```
*Table Name: XXX_XXX
ser     dt              crnt_ts     ser_status
1       2017-11-07      18:15:29        UP
2       2017-11-07      18:15:29        UP
3       2017-11-07      18:15:29        UP
4       2017-11-07      18:15:29        UP
5       2017-11-07      18:15:29        DOWN
6       2017-11-08      18:45:29        UP*
```

If I try to fetch values using `findALL()`, I am getting the below response. If you see the last value which is not matching with DB. How can I solve this issue?

```
[
    {
        "Server": "1",
        "dt": "2017-11-07",
        "crntTs": "18:15:29",
        "serStatus": "UP"
    },
    {
        "Server": "2",
        "dt": "2017-11-07",
        "crntTs": "18:15:29",
        "serStatus": "UP"
    },
    {
        "Server": "3",
        "dt": "2017-11-07",
        "crntTs": "18:15:29",
        "serStatus": "UP"
    },
    {
        "Server": "4",
        "dt": "2017-11-07",
        "crntTs": "18:15:29",
        "serStatus": "UP"
    },
    {
        "Server": "5",
        "dt": "2017-11-07",
        "crntTs": "18:15:29",
        "serStatus": "DOWN"
    },
    {
        "Server": "6",
        "dt": "2017-11-07",
        "crntTs": "18:15:29",
        "serStatus": "DOWN"
    }]
```

Comment: did u commit the changes after inserting /updating the records in DB?

Comment: Yes. I can able to retrieve the valid response if query directly in DB. And I tried the same thing using JDBCTemplate and It fetched the proper inserted value. Only JPA Repository retrieving incorrect values.

Comment: Do you know where the JSON serialization is done?  Is it the DBMS or something in the tools accessing the database?  It seems odd that the extra server should be reported as present but shown with the time information of the other servers.